# Assignment to function parameter 'state' on redux get failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i just learn redux and got this error in my reducer code, they said "Assignment to function parameter 'state'" and make my code break, already follow the eslint suggestion but seems still not working,  here is my code below

```
const fooReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   case 'INC': {
    state = {
     ...state,
     foo: action.payload,
   };
   break;
 }
 case 'DEC': {
   state = {
   ...state,
   lorem: action.payload,
   };
   break;
  }
}
return state;
};
```

[image: error message]
really appriciate your help.

Comment: The error you mentioned in your post and what's in your screenshot are not the same. My answer addresses the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator (`...`) is not being recognized during the build. You'll want to add [the appropriate Babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) in order for webpack to recognize and transpile that code. Merge something like this into your `.babelrc` after doing a dev install of the plugin:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```